# Python: Recursive Function to check if string is a palindrome

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So I'm trying to create a recursive function to check if a word is a palindrome. It should ignore all non-alphabetical characters. Here is what I have so far.

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    '''
    A Recursive Function that returns True if the parameter, text, is a palindrome, False if not.
    Ignores capitalization, punctuation, and spaces.

    text: a String
    returns True or False
    '''
    text = list(text)
    if len(text) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        if text[0].isalpha():
            if text[-1].isalpha():
                if text[0].lower() == text[-1].lower():
                    text.remove(text[0])
                    text.remove(text[-1])
                    return is_palindrome(text)
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                text.remove(text[-1])
                return is_palindrome(text)
        else:
            text.remove(text[0])
            return is_palindrome(text)
```

Here are some test cases...

---

`is_palindrome("abcde")`

Results

```
abcde
False
```

---

```
is_palindrome("aabbaa")
```

**Results**

```
aabbaa
['b', 'b', 'a', 'a']
False
```

---

```
is_palindrome("aa bb cc")
```

**Results**

```
aa bb aa
[' ', 'b', 'b', ' ', 'a', 'a']
['b', 'b', ' ', 'a', 'a']
False
```

---

So for some reason, it always directly ends up being false.

Thoughts on how to solve this? All help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`text.remove(text[0])` does not do what you think it does (It removes the first occurrence of that value from the list). To remove by index use slices. You can rewrite this:

```
text.remove(text[0])
text.remove(text[-1])
```

to this:

```
text = text[1:-1]
```

Comment: beat me to it! Was going to give the same response!

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls `remove(x)` removes the first occurence of the element `x` in a list. [1,2,5].remove(5) results in `[1,2]`. Note that `remove` is an in-place operation - it will modify the original list _directly_, rather than modifying a copy of it.

Comment: Also there was no need to convert variable `text` to a list. Python is smart enough to be able to do slicing/indexing on strings too :-)

Comment: @AkshatMahajan

So slicing on the other hand modifies a copy of it?

Comment: @user1434070

Alright. I did that since it gave me an error back when I had "remove" in there. Thanks!

Comment: @Help_Python_Pls No, slicing _returns_ a  new list with only the elements you asked for. Not a copy (that would imply the whole list was originally copied) and not modified (that would imply this new list had some of its elements removed) - but I suppose this is all just semantics. The net effect is, yes, exactly as you describe.

Comment: @AkshatMahajan Makes sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Is this just for fun, or an exercise?  I don't think recursion really makes sense here:

```
def palindrome(s):
    l = len(s)
    m = l // 2
    return s[:m][::-1] == s[m + (l % 2):]
```

Then I'd just preprocess the input to remove non alphanumerics and uppers like:

```
s = 'aBc%$cbA'
palindrome(re.subn('\W', '', s)[0].lower())
```

Comment: Its an exercise. But yeah. Don't need recursion for this. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

From the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/datastructures.html):

> list.**remove**(*x*)
>
> Remove the first item from the list whose value is x. It is an error if there is no such item.

When you call `text.remove(text[-1])` for the list based on the string `aabbaa`, the first `a` in the list will be removed, which is not always the desired behavior. If you want to remove the first and last elements of the list, you can use a slice as user1434070 posted. An alternate method is to use `list.pop(x)` to remove the element with a specified index, which is accomplished by replacing the calls to `remove` with the following code:

```
text.pop(0)
if len(text) == 0:
    return True
text.pop(-1)
```

Note that the size of the list must be checked after the first `pop` in case it contained a single letter. This occurs in the deepest level of recursion when the original palindrome contains an odd number of characters.

Answer (score 0):

`list.remove()` removes the first occurrence of an element in the `list`. If that element is present at the beginning and end, it doesn't matter that you selected that element by indexing the `list` to get the last element - it'll still remove the first one it sees. `list.pop()` would be more appropriate, as that removes elements based on their index rather than their value.

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    text = list(text)
    if len(text) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        if text[0].isalpha():
            if text[-1].isalpha():
                if text[0].lower() == text[-1].lower():
                    text.pop(0)
                    text.pop()
                    return is_palindrome(text)
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                text.pop()
                return is_palindrome(text)
        else:
            text.pop(0)
            return is_palindrome(text)
```

However, you can further improve your program by filtering out any ignored characters at the beginning:

```
def is_palindrome(text):
    text = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, text)).lower()
    if not text:
        return True
    text = list(text)
    if text[0].lower() == text[-1].lower():
        text.pop(0)
        text.pop()
        return is_palindrome(text)
    return False
```

A further optimization would be to use a default argument to note whether the string has been cleaned already, and send a slice to the recursive call:

```
def is_palindrome(text, cleaned=False):
    if not cleaned:
        text = ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, text)).lower()
    if not text:
        return True
    if text[0] != text[-1]:
        return False
    return is_palindrome(text[1:-1], 1)
```